# Python: Tribonacci sequence - what is the difference in these codes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, slice

I am trying to solve a codewars (http://www.codewars.com) challenge:

**6 kyu : Fibonacci, Tribonacci and friends**

---

The challenge:

Think of a Quadribonacci starting with a signature of 4 elements and each following element is the sum of the 4 previous, a Pentabonacci (well Cinquebonacci would probably sound a bit more italian, but it would also sound really awful) with a signature of 5 elements and each following element is the sum of the 5 previous, and so on.

You have to build a Xbonacci function that takes a signature of X elements - and remember each next element is the sum of the last X elements - and returns the first n elements of the so seeded sequence.

---

But I can't seem to understant the difference between this two functions.
The first one was rejected, whereas the second was accepted.

rejected code:

```
def Xbonacci(signature, num):    
    a_list = signature[:] 
    final_list = signature[:]

    for i in range(0, num-len(signature)):     

        a = sum( a_list[ :len(a_list)] )                 
        final_list.append(a)                  
        a_list.append(a)    
        a_list.remove(a_list[0])

    return final_list
```

accepted code:

```
def Xbonacci(signature,n):
    result = signature[:]

    for x in range(n-len(signature)):
        current_fib = 0
        start = len(result) - len(signature)
        for y in result[start:]:
            current_fib += y
        result.append(current_fib)

    return result[:n]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The two functions have different behaviour when `n < len(signature)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two functions have different behaviour when `n < len(signature)`.

Function 1:

```
>>> Xbonacci([1, 2, 3], 1)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Function 2:

```
>>> Xbonacci([1, 2, 3], 1)
[1]
```

Since the challenge says "returns the first n elements of the so-seeded sequence", the first function is incorrect.